# Converting List into custom objects

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-to-xml

I am reading an XML document using the XDocument library and querying into a list with LINQ in C#. I am returning an anoymous list into an implicit var. The anynmous type is a simple  structure. I am not sure what I am doing wrong but would like to return this into a List of a class I already defined but am getting an error converting this anonymous type into my custom class. Am I missing something obvious on this on. I do not want to use dynamic typing here.

```
public class CustomClass
    {
        public string id { get; set; }
        public int fileName { get; set; }
    }

XDocument optXML = XDocument.Load(pathName);

var optInput = (from item in optXML.Descendants("Group")
                    select new
                    {
                        id = (int)item.Attribute("ID"),
                        fileName = (string)item.Attribute("FileName")
                    }).ToList();
foreach (CustomClass item in optInput)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item.id);
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `var` instead of custom type, it will be the type generated by the compiler in your projection use new.

```
foreach (var item in optInput)
{
     Console.WriteLine(item.id);
}
```

or you can create object of your class i.e `CustomClass` instead of using anonymous type.

```
  var optInput = (from item in optXML.Descendants("Group")
                select new CustomClass 
                {
                    id = (int)item.Attribute("ID"),
                    fileName = (string)item.Attribute("FileName")
                }).ToList();
```

Comment: Is there a way to import directly into the custom class like List<CustomClass> = (from item in optXML.Descendants("Group")
                            select new
                            {
                                id = (int)item.Attribute("ID"),
                                fileName = (string)item.Attribute("FileName")
                            }).ToList();

Answer (score 4):

Instead of selecting a `new{}` select a `new CustomClass()`:

```
public class CustomClass
    {
        public string id { get; set; }
        public int fileName { get; set; }
    }

XDocument optXML = XDocument.Load(pathName);

var optInput = (from item in optXML.Descendants("Group")
                    select new CustomClass()
                    {
                        id = (int)item.Attribute("ID"),
                        fileName = (string)item.Attribute("FileName")
                    }).ToList();
foreach (CustomClass item in optInput)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item.id);
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you want to project into `CustomClass` rather than an anonymous object

```
List<CustomClass> optInput = (from item in optXML.Descendants("Group")
                select new CustomClass 
                {
                    id = (int)item.Attribute("ID"),
                    fileName = (string)item.Attribute("FileName")
                }).ToList();
```

There's no specific reason to change `var` in your code to `List<CustomClass>` - ive just done it to demonstrate to you what you're actually getting.

Answer (score 1):

You're getting this error because the anonymous type you select inside your query is NOT CustomClass. You can simply select Customclass itself like so

```
    select new CustomClass { id = , fileName = }
```

or use the anomymous type like so inside the foreach

```
    foreach (var item in optInput) 
    { 
        Console.WriteLine(item.id); 
    }
```

and you'll get full intellisense for it.